# How can I get Sanguine Rose?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How can I get the Sanguine Rose that summons a Dremora?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must finish the [A Night To Remember](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Night_To_Remember) quest to get the [Sanguine Rose](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sanguine_Rose).

This quest will only start once you reach level 14. You will need to meet with [Sam Guevenne](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sam_Guevenne) to start the quest. He will randomly spawn in any of the inns or taverns across Skyrim, including those in towns, not just the ones in hold capitals.

<sup>Source and more info at: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Night_To_Remember</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you go to any of the taverns in Skyrim, then once you are at least level 14, he will challenge you to a drinking contest and give you 3 flagons. After you drink them, you will blackout and wake up to a woman, who will say that you had blacked out and then send you on a quest. You will get sanguines rose as a reward.

Answer (score -3):

He will spawn at a random bar across skyrim.. When you find him, he will challenge you to a drinking competition.. Then you undergo few tasks and then meet him at a fort.. Then when everything is over, you will get the weapon..

Comment: This answer doesn't really add anything that the existing answers haven't already covered.

Answer (score -5):

You can meet a man at level 15 to 20 in Whiterun named Sanguine, and he challenges you to a drinking competition.  One problem is that you need to down three drinks in order to win the contest, and that's where the real fun beings.

Comment: This is grossly inaccurate and only barely attempts to answer the question. -1